# jQuery popup (bPopup) fails to load iFrame

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I have created a popup that loads .php site using the jQuery plugin: [bpopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/).

Problem is that plugin won't load website that is coded in php. Can someone told me where is problem?

This is code that I am using:

JavaScript:

```
$('#leader').bind('click', function (e) {
    // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
    e.preventDefault();
    // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
    $('#leaderboard').bPopup({
        modalClose: false,
        opacity: '0',
        positionStyle: 'fixed', //'fixed' or 'absolute'
        content: 'iframe', //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image'
        contentContainer: '.content',
        loadUrl: 'http://remake.hr/memtest/leaderboard.php' //Uses jQuery.load()
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="leaderboard" class="info"></div>
<div class="button" id="leader"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.info {
    display:none;
    width:700px;
    background: rgb(38, 170, 225);
    /* Fall-back for browsers that don't support rgba */
    background: rgba(38, 170, 225, .9);
    color:white;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 25px 50px 50px 25px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle of your code? Also confirm that you are checking on localhost or sever..

Comment: I'm not familiar with `bpopup`, but I assume `loadUrl` property is using `jQuery.load()` in some way? If that's the case, shouldn't it have callbacks for `complete, error, && success` and if so, can you not use those in conjunction with developer tools to find the problem? I get the feeling this is an ajax issue. Either you're php is not returning the expected `STRING` or the ajax is not established correctly to expect what you are returning. Are you using `echo` to return an HTML STRING?

Comment: Also, as Jeroen points out, `contentContainer: '.content',` isn't connected to anything we can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an inner div tag to your HTML with `class="content"`

With `contentContainer: '.content'`, you specify this container.

Resulting HTML:

```
<div id="leaderboard" class="info"><div class="content"></div></div>
<div class="button" id="leader"></div>
```

Comment: Lol totally looked over that. Was looking at this plugin thing. I've gotten so used to just writing my own when i need them, that these plugin questions always throw me a little.

Comment: +1 Yeah me too.. A few adjustments and you should be all set @user2496520

Comment: Thanks for code @JeroenNoten. It's working great now!